# How to prevent crashes when giving invalid quaternion to Gazebo GUI camera

Tags: gazebo

From what I understand, {0,0,0,0} is not a valid quaternion. Therefore when I enter `gz service -s /gui/move_to/pose --reqtype gz.msgs.GUICamera --reptype gz.msgs.Boolean --timeout 500 --req 'pose: {position:{x: 27.2, y:-1.7215,z:2.2255}, orientation:{x:0, y:0, z:0, w:0}}'`, Gazebo crashes. Is there a way to modify the source code to check if arguments are valid before executing, in order to prevent such crashes?

Comment: If there isn't a built-in method, you could just write a "wrapper-script".

Comment: This should be a straightforward modification to the Gazebo source to check the norm of the quaternion and make sure it's within some reasonable tolerance of 1.0. Seems like an issue to raise on the relevant Gazebo repo.

Comment: Which version of Gazebo are you using and what is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: I raised an issue on [gazebosim/gz-math](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-math/issues/578) regarding the same. As for the solution, where should we be adding these checks?